# CSR Racing 2 - Fastest Half Mile Tier 5 Car to buy with Cash?

Tags: csr-racing-2

I am currently playing CSR Racing 2 on Mobile and have gotten to Tier 5. 
Now I have the option of 3 cars to buy with the money earned from winning Tier 4.

The 3 Cars are the Lamborghini Huracan, Ferrrari F12 Berlinetta, and the Mclaren 570s.

After each car is fitted with all Stage 5 parts (Not stage 6) and tuned to the best they can be, which of these 3 cars is the best for half-mile races and can finish in the fastest time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think they might be the same performance at the end, because CSR 2 depends on how many Fusion parts implemented and how many Stage 6 upgrades fitted + Tuning so if as you say all of them with same amount of Fusion Part, same upgrades and same level of tuning I think its hard to say there will be a difference in time